# How to change quantity in mysql by 10%-20% in quantity column.

Tags: mysql

I have a column called quantity with 1000 rows of data. I want mysql to change all the quantities randomly, increasing quantity by 10%-20%

Comment: It is important that you post what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
UPDATE your_table
SET quantity = quantity*(1.1+RAND()*.1)
```

Comment: yh its just stackoverflow says I have to wait for a few minutes before   accepting. Do you know how to change a date by +- 5 days randomly?

Comment: I'll let you search by yourself on this one. Using rand() function and [this syntax](http://davidwalsh.name/add-dates-mysql), you should be able to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this update statement

```
update mytable
set quantity = quantity * (1.1 + rand() * 0.1)
```